# Updating the file path for a Google Earth layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-earth, update, kmz

I have exported a lot of our data from ArcMap to Google Earth. Most of our company prefers to use Google Earth for basic searches. The users within the company have downloaded a "Master" Google Earth file which has all of our GIS layers.

I have updated some of the layers in ArcMap and have exported them as KMZ. If I change the file path of the layers to show updated data in the "Master" on my PC, will all users in the company automatically get the updates the next time they start Google Earth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your users downloaded a NetworkLink KML that points to the data KML/KMZ on a server or shared drive somewhere, then yes anytime they open Earth (or manually refresh) they will load the latest data. On the other hand, if each user downloaded the actual data KML, then they will need to re-download to get fresh data.

Comment: Thank you very much. Our users download the Master KML from our group drive, so it is safe to say that their data automatically updates?

Comment: If I correctly understood how you provided the data to users, then NO, they will not see updated data in Earth if you simply update the Master KML on your Group Drive. They downloaded it and will just keep seeing the version as it was when they downloaded it.  If you want them to get future updates, then have each of them delete the current "Master KML" from Earth, and provide a KML file that's a NetworkLink which points to the Master KML... that way, every time they open Earth, the NetworkLink will re-fetch the latest data.